# How can I remove displays that don't actually exist?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have an MSI gaming laptop, on which I am running the latest version of Windows 10 Pro.  I plug in an additional 34-inch ultra-wide-screen monitor via HDMI, so I have two monitors.  But in my Display Settings I see something quite strange:

[image: Display Settings]

I do not have, nor have I ever had, six monitors.  I have tried everything to remove the references to those monitors by opening the `Multiple Displays` drop-down and disabling monitors 3, 4, 5 and 6--all to no avail.

While the set-up works well, it suffers from one problem.  Occasionally when I open a new window, it goes to one of the non-existent monitors, and I have to use the `Windows` and arrow keys to bring it to one of my existing monitors.

How can I remove the references to these ghost monitors?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you update to a newer graphics driver to alleviate the problem or did you need to drop back to an older one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the rare occasions that I have seen this happen before, it is usually caused by the display driver.

Faced with the same scenario, I would [manually create a System Restore point](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4571-system-restore-point-create-windows-10-a.html) as a potential fall-back and then check for an updated graphics driver to install.  If you are already running the latest version, try dropping back to an older version and see if it alleviates the problem.